# LTSpice Zener diode bug?

Tags: diodes, ltspice, zener, debugging

I'm trying to design a circuit using a zener diode but am having issues getting it to work right. 
[image: Working zener diode circuit]

This circuit works fine and show Vout = 6.198V. However, if I swap their positions - 
[image: Dysfunctional zener diode circuit]

Here, Vout = 200.364V. Why is this happening? Why does the anode of the zener diode need to be referenced to ground? I expected it to be 200-6.2 = 193.8V

Comment: If you do a .TRAN analysis you will get the value you expect. The operating point calculation assumes, I think, that the diode is forward biased as an initial assumption. That's a starting point for the analysis. But it's not the end-point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the LTspice documentation on `.op`:

> There is no guarantee that the operating point of a general nonlinear
>   circuit can be found with successive linear approximations as is done
>   in Newton-Raphson iteration.

This circuit is non-linear and LTspice fails to detect by itself that Newton iteration fails. Disabling Newton iteration by `.options NoOpIter` forces LTspice to try different methods for operating point calculations. In this case it opts for Gmin stepping instead and finds the correct result:

```
Gmin stepping succeeded in finding the operating point.

Semiconductor Device Operating Points:
                        --- Diodes ---
Name:      d1
Model: bzx84b6v2l
Id:     -9.69e-04
Vd:     -6.18e+00
Req:     1.36e+01
CAP:     4.80e-09
```